# Is the product of two sets with measures $0$ in $\mathbb(R)$ measures $0$

Tags: real-analysis

The definition in this case of product of two measurable sets in $\Bbb R$ is 
$$A\cdot B=\{x \in \mathbb R:x=x'\cdot x'',\ x' \in A,\ x''\in B\}$$
My question: When $A,\ B$ have the measure $0$, is it always the case that $A\cdot B$ has the measure of $0$. I already have the result if $m(A)=m(B)=0,$ $m(A+B)$ isn't always $0$, as is the case with the Cantor Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from OP's *Question*:

I already have the result if ()=()=0, (+) isn't always $\,0\,\,$ (and even $\,m(A+B)>0\,$ is possible).

Thus it's not hard to see that there are such $\,A\,B\,$ contained in $\,J:=[0;1].\,$
Define
$$\,C\,:=\,\{\exp(x): x\in A\}\qquad \mbox{and}\qquad D\,:=\,\{\exp(x):x\in B\} $$

Then
$\,C\cdot D=\exp(A+D)\,\,$ hence $\,\,m(C)=m(D)=0\,$ and $\,m(C\cdot D)>0.$